# compare value with cells use VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the data(number) 2 cell(Excel) as a  cell.

[image: Pic]

I want to compare between Data1 and Data2 each number. if found difference data then move to difference column(new cell) and if found same data then move to same column(new cell). finally, Move the data difference and same to difference+same column.

```
Data1 = ,4016,4053,6008,6009,6010,6011,24016,24022,24029,24035,24041,24045,24053,24059,24071,24077,24214,24240,24258,24262,24268,26000,26001,26002,26003,26004,26005,26006,26007


Data2 = ,4001,6008,6009,6010,6011,24001,24030,24036,24042,24046,24049,24054,24060,24072,24078,24215,24241,24259,24263,24269,26000,26001,26002,26003,26004,26005,26006,26007
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Split the numbers into arrays (so we can handle each number)
2. Add all numbers to a dictionary `AllButUniqueItems` once so it contains each number of each data set once. All all numbers that are already in this dictionary into the `DuplicateItems` dictionary.
3. Unique items are then all the items that are in `AllButUniqueItems` **but not** in `DuplicateItems`
4. Use the logic of (3) to concatenate the numbers to strings and write them into cells.

[image]

So you end up with something like

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DifferentOrSame()
    'read and split data sets into array
    Dim DataSet1 As Variant
    DataSet1 = Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("A2").Value, ",")

    Dim DataSet2 As Variant
    DataSet2 = Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("B2").Value, ",")

    Dim AllButUniqueItems As Object
    Set AllButUniqueItems = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim DuplicateItems As Object
    Set DuplicateItems = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim itm As Variant
    'process data set 1
    For Each itm In DataSet1
        If AllButUniqueItems.Exists(itm) Then
            If Not DuplicateItems.Exists(itm) Then
                DuplicateItems.Add itm, 1
            End If
        Else
            AllButUniqueItems.Add itm, 1
        End If
    Next itm

    'process data set 2
    For Each itm In DataSet2
        If AllButUniqueItems.Exists(itm) Then
            If Not DuplicateItems.Exists(itm) Then
                DuplicateItems.Add itm, 1
            End If
        Else
             AllButUniqueItems.Add itm, 1
        End If
    Next itm

    'concatenate strings
    Dim StrDuplicates As String, StrUniques As String, StrAllButUnique As String
    For Each itm In AllButUniqueItems 
        StrAllButUnique = StrAllButUnique & IIf(StrAllButUnique <> vbNullString, ",", "") & itm

        If Not DuplicateItems.Exists(itm) Then
            StrUniques = StrUniques & IIf(StrUniques <> vbNullString, ",", "") & itm
        Else
            StrDuplicates = StrDuplicates & IIf(StrDuplicates <> vbNullString, ",", "") & itm
        End If
    Next itm

    'write to cells
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("C2").Value = "'" & StrDuplicates
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("D2").Value = "'" & StrUniques
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("E2").Value = "'" & StrAllButUnique
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it is show error.  `For Each itm In UniqueItems` The value in UniqueItems = Empty

Comment: The value in UniqueItems = Empty

Comment: I put the data in A2 and B3 like you suggest.

Comment: @Mr.Chat my fault it must be `For Each itm In AllButUniqueItems` fixed the answer.